# Obter uso da CPU de um processo em int C#

Tags: c#

Preciso obter uso da CPU de um processo que é uma variável.

Ex.:

```
var process = wait.exe
```

E verificar o wait.exe, se ele chegou aos 100 uso CPU.

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: "**_se ele chegou aos 100 uso CPU_**". O que você quer dizer com isso?

Comment: É isto que pretende? [I need to call accurate CPU usage of a single process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462331/i-need-to-call-accurate-cpu-usage-of-a-single-process)

Comment: @jbueno acho que ele quis dizer 100% de uso do processador no gerenciador de tarefas.

Comment: , isso obter o uso da CPU do que o processo esta usando ex: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/888/941/full/Capturar.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `PerformanceCounter` que está no namespace  `System.Diagnostics`

```
public int GetCpuUsage()
{
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    cpuCounter = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("wait").First().ProcessName);
    return (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();

}
```